# If-then statement based two player python Tic-Tac-Toe program

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this basic `if-then` statement tic tac toe game but its super repetitive.I was wondering if there is a simpler way to make this look more elegant and run more efficiently. I basically want make a 3x3 grid with coordinates 1-9. Then I prompt player one to enter a location and that location is replaced with either an `X` or an `O`. Then I repeated until a completed board is achieved. Here is my code.

```
import sys


def game():
    global z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, z9
    print("Player one is X player two is O \n")

    X1 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your first X?: "))
    if X1 == 1:
        z1 = "X"
    elif X1 == 2:
        z2 = "X"
    elif X1 == 3:
        z3 = "X"
    elif X1 == 4:
        z4 = "X"
    elif X1 == 5:
        z5 = "X"
    elif X1 == 6:
        z6 = "X"
    elif X1 == 7:
        z7 = "X"
    elif X1 == 8:
        z8 = "X"
    elif X1 == 9:
        z9 = "X"
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    O1 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your first O?: "))
    if O1 == 1:
        z1 = "O"
    elif O1 == 2:
        z2 = "O"
    elif O1 == 3:
        z3 = "O"
    elif O1 == 4:
        z4 = "O"
    elif O1 == 5:
        z5 = "O"
    elif O1 == 6:
        z6 = "O"
    elif O1 == 7:
        z7 = "O"
    elif O1 == 8:
        z8 = "O"
    elif O1 == 9:
        z9 = "O"
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    X2 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next X?: "))
    if X2 == 1:
        z1 = "X"
    elif X2 == 2:
        z2 = "X"
    elif X2 == 3:
        z3 = "X"
    elif X2 == 4:
        z4 = "X"
    elif X2 == 5:
        z5 = "X"
    elif X2 == 6:
        z6 = "X"
    elif X2 == 7:
        z7 = "X"
    elif X2 == 8:
        z8 = "X"
    elif X2 == 9:
        z9 = "X"
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    O2 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next O?: "))
    if O2 == 1:
        z1 = "O"
    elif O2 == 2:
        z2 = "O"
    elif O2 == 3:
        z3 = "O"
    elif O2 == 4:
        z4 = "O"
    elif O2 == 5:
        z5 = "O"
    elif O2 == 6:
        z6 = "O"
    elif O2 == 7:
        z7 = "O"
    elif O2 == 8:
        z8 = "O"
    elif O2 == 9:
        z9 = "O"
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    X3 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next X?: "))
    if X3 == 1:
        z1 = "X"
    elif X3 == 2:
        z2 = "X"
    elif X3 == 3:
        z3 = "X"
    elif X3 == 4:
        z4 = "X"
    elif X3 == 5:
        z5 = "X"
    elif X3 == 6:
        z6 = "X"
    elif X3 == 7:
        z7 = "X"
    elif X3 == 8:
        z8 = "X"
    elif X3 == 9:
        z9 = "X"
    board()
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    O3 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next O?: "))
    if O3 == 1:
        z1 = "O"
    elif O3 == 2:
        z2 = "O"
    elif O3 == 3:
        z3 = "O"
    elif O3 == 4:
        z4 = "O"
    elif O3 == 5:
        z5 = "O"
    elif O3 == 6:
        z6 = "O"
    elif O3 == 7:
        z7 = "O"
    elif O3 == 8:
        z8 = "O"
    elif O3 == 9:
        z9 = "O"
    board()
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    X4 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next X?: "))
    if X4 == 1:
        z1 = "X"
    elif X4 == 2:
        z2 = "X"
    elif X4 == 3:
        z3 = "X"
    elif X4 == 4:
        z4 = "X"
    elif X4 == 5:
        z5 = "X"
    elif X4 == 6:
        z6 = "X"
    elif X4 == 7:
        z7 = "X"
    elif X4 == 8:
        z8 = "X"
    elif X4 == 9:
        z9 = "X"
    board()
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    O4 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next O?: "))
    if O4 == 1:
        z1 = "O"
    elif O4 == 2:
        z2 = "O"
    elif O4 == 3:
        z3 = "O"
    elif O4 == 4:
        z4 = "O"
    elif O4 == 5:
        z5 = "O"
    elif O4 == 6:
        z6 = "O"
    elif O4 == 7:
        z7 = "O"
    elif O4 == 8:
        z8 = "O"
    elif O4 == 9:
        z9 = "O"
    board()
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
    X5 = int(input("Player one, where would you like to put your next X?: "))
    if X5 == 1:
        z1 = "X"
    elif X5 == 2:
        z2 = "X"
    elif X5 == 3:
        z3 = "X"
    elif X5 == 4:
        z4 = "X"
    elif X5 == 5:
        z5 = "X"
    elif X5 == 6:
        z6 = "X"
    elif X5 == 7:
        z7 = "X"
    elif X5 == 8:
        z8 = "X"
    elif X5 == 9:
        z9 = "X"
    board()
    print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
    print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
    print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)

def board():

    if z1 == 'X' and z2 == "X" and z3 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z4 == 'X' and z5 == "X" and z6 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z7 == 'X' and z8 == "X" and z9 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z1 == 'X' and z4 == "X" and z7 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z2 == 'X' and z5 == "X" and z8 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z3 == 'X' and z6 == "X" and z9 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z1 == 'X' and z5 == "X" and z9 == "X":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z3 == 'X' and z5 == "X" and z7 == "X":
        print("X wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z1 == 'O' and z2 == "O" and z3 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z4 == 'O' and z5 == "O" and z6 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z7 == 'O' and z8 == "O" and z9 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z1 == 'O' and z4 == "O" and z7 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z2 == 'O' and z5 == "O" and z8 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z3 == 'O' and z6 == "O" and z9 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z1 == 'O' and z5 == "O" and z9 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()
    elif z3 == 'O' and z5 == "O" and z7 == "O":
        print(z1, "|", z2, "|", z3)
        print(z4, "|", z5, "|", z6)
        print(z7, "|", z8, "|", z9)
        print("O wins")
        sys.exit()

print("Here is your Tic-Tac-Toe board")

z1 = ' '
z2 = ' '
z3 = ' '
z4 = ' '
z5 = ' '
z6 = ' '
z7 = ' '
z8 = ' '
z9 = ' '
print("(1) | (2) | (3)")
print("(4) | (5) | (6)")
print("(7) | (8) | (9)")

game()
```

Comment: You should really look into making use of functions, loops and arrays... Make functions for check move, update, checkGameOver etc...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would be helping you if I gave you a complete script here, but I will give you something I came up with on the fly that may get you thinking of some new approaches. I have (on purpose) not added any win/loss logic, nor will it ask for more than one input from each player; but, this should help you to expand your thinking.

Consider combining an object oriented approach with the procedural one you've already taken. Below, the game board is shown as an object (object oriented paradigm) that each play interacts with via a function (procedural paradigm); although each player could also be an object themselves and each function could be a method of their respective class.

```
class board():
    # make the entire board a dictionary that can be accessed via keys
    board = {"z1": "-", "z2": "-", "z3": "-",
             "z4": "-", "z5": "-", "z6": "-",
             "z7": "-", "z8": "-", "z9": "-"}

    # method that uses passed in variables to change board values by key
    def set_z(self, choice, player_symbol):
        self.board[choice] = player_symbol

    # method to print the current state of the board using dictionary 
    # keys
    def show_board(self):
        print(self.board["z1"], "|", self.board["z2"], "|", 
              self.board["z3"])
        print(self.board["z4"], "|", self.board["z5"], "|", 
              self.board["z6"])
        print(self.board["z7"], "|", self.board["z8"], "|",  
              elf.board["z9"])

# instantiate the board class above as an object called 'new_board'            
new_board = board()

# access the instantiated object via its setter method 'set_z'
# and print the current state of the board object
def x_player_input():
    X1 = input("Player one, where would you like to put your first X?: ")
    new_board.set_z(X1, 'X')
    new_board.show_board()

def o_player_input():
    O1 = input("Player two, where would you like to put your first o?: ")
    new_board.set_z(O1, 'O')
    new_board.show_board()

# this just calls each player input method once; you would need to think
# of a way to call these until some win/loss logic declares the game's 
# outcome
x_player_input()
o_player_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I did almost the same for my first Tic-Tac-Toe implementation. It's quite hard to be sure that you really covered all scenarios in such if-else conditions. At the same time there is a solution for this task which allows one to implement the Tic-Tac-Toe game in a 5-10 lines of code. Just have a look at [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm.